# TODO List updating with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

So I have this simple todo list with an ajax call to update the field `completed` in my database to either 1 or 0, when I click on a li item.

The code in my view is not good, obviously, and it ofcourse doesn't work. Only the first time, when I click on a li, it does get updated, but I need to refresh if I want it to work again, since the `data-completed` doesn't get updated. I need jquery to do that, but I have no clue how to update a data-attribute to either 1 or 0 based on the original value.

Any pointers as to how to make this work properly will be greatly appreciated.

View:

```
<li data-id='{!! $task->id !!}' data-completed='@if($task->completed == '1') 0 @else 1 @endif'>
```

AJAX Call:

```
$('li').on('click', function(e){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/tasks/update/'+$(this).data('id')+'/'+$(this).data('completed'),
        method: 'GET'
    })
});
```

Since I am using laravel, this is my route:

```
Route::get('api/tasks/update/{id}/{completed}', function($id, $completed) {
    $task = App\Task::find($id);

    $task->completed = $completed;

    $task->save();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few things you need to do here:

First, you don't need your if statement if you're already saving 0/1 in the database, so you can simplify your view portion:

```
<li data-id='{!! $task->id !!}' data-completed='{{ $task->completed }}'>
```

Second, you'll need to return the updated task so that you can update your view:

```
Route::get('api/tasks/update/{id}/{completed}', function($id, $completed) {
    $task = App\Task::find($id);

    $task->completed = $completed;

    $task->save();

    return response()->json($task);
});
```

Then, update your ajax call so that when the updated `task` is returned, you can update your list:

```
$('li').on('click', function(e){
    var completed = (!$(this).data('completed') ? 1 : 0);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/tasks/update/'+$(this).data('id')+'/'+$(this).data('completed'),
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
          $(this).data('completed', data.completed);
       },
    })
});
```

Something I would also do is update your route and AJAX calls to `POST`, as this is just good practice for when you're updating data:

PHP

```
Route::post('api/tasks/update/{id}', function(Request $request, $id) {
    $task = App\Task::find($id);

    $completed = $request->input('completed');

    $task->completed = $completed;

    $task->save();

    return response()->json($task);
});
```

JS

```
$('li').on('click', function(e){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/tasks/update/'+$(this).data('id'),
        data: {completed: (!$(this).data('completed') ? 1 : 0)},
        method: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
          $(this).data('completed', data.completed);
       },
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm, except for one thing. With the above, the database doesn't get updated, since the reverse of `completed` should be passed in the ajax call, not the value that I got from the database. I tried `data: {completed: !$(this).data('completed')},` but with the exclamation mark the value that is passed is either `true` or `false`, which is fine, but it doesn't set the value in the database to either `0` or `1` like this. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've added in a ternary to convert truthy/falsy values to their 1/0 counterparts which should work for you. You can also do this in the controller, but it makes more sense to send the correct value to the controller rather than converting it there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand ternary's and all that in PHP but when it comes to javascript, I'm lost. I need to follow some tutorials to understand it better :)